# How to load new ajax contents to an exist opened [ selected ] tab in JQuery UI Tabs plugin?

Tags: jquery, ajax, user-interface, tabs

E.g:

I create a new blank tab and its empty contents dynamic via an **add new tab button**.Just like **firefox** and **chrome** to click **add new tab** to create a new tab browser window. And then I **click other links** to **load contents** to **the new created or current selected tab.****E.g**:

When **Tab1** was **selected**,I click the **link3** and load **the contents of link3 to the Tab1**.

So,I could using the current tab to load other external contents!

Thank you very much!!

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To load a url in to the current tab you can do something like this:

```
$(".moreContent").click(function( event ){
    event.preventDefault();
    loadContent( this.href );
});
function loadContent( url ) {
    var selected = $tabs.tabs('option', 'selected');
    $tabs.tabs("url", selected , url ).tabs("load", selected);
}
```

Where the links you want to load in to the tabs have the class `moreContent`.

Here is a full example.  Doesn't fully work because the /echo/html/ content has to be from a post request but should give you the idea.

http://jsfiddle.net/petersendidit/hsatf/